# Make Keycloak SSO Cookie Valid only for current browser tab

Tags: cookies, single-sign-on, keycloak

We have Keycloak configured for SSO across several of our web UIs. As people navigate our UIs they jump into other UIs in the same tab and that UI will then do a SSO authentication using its **client_id** for the UI.

What we want to achieve is that when the user closes the tab or browser window we want the **KEYCLOAK_SESSION** cookie to be unusable so that if a user opens a tab and navigates to our Web UI they will be asked to login in again.

Even if we set the Keycloak

- **Access Token** expiry to 5 minutes and
- **SSO Session Idle** to say 20 minutes

this is still unacceptable from our security team as the **KEYCLOAK_SESSION** cookie is not a session cookie and will be usable to reauthenticate without login within a 20 minute window.

Is there a way to make the **KEYCLOAK_SESSION** cookie tied to the **tab_id** we used on the initial SSO login such that when the browser is closed and reloaded we generate a new **tab_id** and it won't match the one in the **KEYCLOAK_SESSION** cookie and hence force a re-login?

Comment: Shane, did you ever figure this out?  We are running into the same issue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @manrysj no we never did find a way around it